# A group whose all elements are of order 1 or 2 is Abelian.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose you have $(G, \cdot)$a group whose all elements are either of order $1$ or $2$. Show that it's abelian.

My proof, suppose you have $a,b \in G$ such that $a^1 = e$ and $b^1 =e$ then:
$$a \cdot b= e \cdot e = b \cdot a$$

Now suppose we have $a^1 = e$ and $b^2 = e$:
$$a \cdot b = e \cdot b  = b \cdot e = b \cdot a$$

And finally suppose $a^2 = e$ and $b^2 = e$ then:
$$a \cdot b = a \cdot ( a^{-1} \cdot a ) \cdot b = (a^{-1})(a^2)b=a^{-1}b$$
and $$ b \cdot a = b  (b^{-1} \cdot b ) a = b^{-1}(b^2)a = b^{-1}a$$
Thus we have $$(a\cdot b)(b\cdot a)= (a^{-1} \cdot b)(b^{-1} \cdot a)= e$$
Thus $ab=ba$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Well only $e$ is of order $1$...

Comment: How do you get $ab=ba$ from $(ab)(ba)=e$?

Comment: You have shown that $ab$ and $ba$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: If $a^2 = e$, then $a^{-1} = a$.

Comment: Your proof is a little bit confusing, you did not detail your argument. I will give a hint, maybe it makes things clearer. First you have to notice that $a = a^{-1}$, $b = b^{-1}$ and $ab = (ab)^{-1}$, then you use that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that OP John Mayne's questions about his attempt have been sufficiently addressed by other users; the key, I think, is to realize that $g^2 = e \Longleftrightarrow g = g^{-1}$, ***viz:***

The condition

$\forall g \in G (g^1 = e \vee g^2 = e) \tag 1$

is logically equivalent to

$\forall g \in G (g^2 = e), \tag 2$

since

$(g^1 = e \Longleftrightarrow g = e) \tag 3$

and

$g = e \Longrightarrow g^2 = e; \tag 4$

therefore we need to show

$\forall g \in G (g^2 = e) \Longrightarrow \forall a, b \in G (ab = ba). \tag 5$

Now

$\forall g \in G (g^2 = e \Longleftrightarrow g^{-1}g^2 = g^{-1}e \Longleftrightarrow g = g^{-1}); \tag 6$

thus

$\forall a, b \in G (ab = a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ba)^{-1} = ba). \tag 7$

Comment: @amWhy:  agreed . . . sort of.  I wanted to type out of the context set by the question, hence  my (1).

Comment: Yes, as I read through your answer, I see that you were arguing that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$  Hence, I've deleted my comment ;-)

Comment: @amWhy:  thanks.  Good to hear from you again!

Answer (score 6):

Your first two cases are a little inelegant, since $a^1 = e$ means that $a=e$.  So the property that every element is of order 1 or 2 can be simplified to requiring $$x^2 = e,\; \forall  x \in G.$$

Here is a streamlined version.  Let $a, b \in G$ and let $x = ab$.  Since $x^2 = e$, we have
$$
    abab = e
$$
Multiply on the right by $b$ and remember that $b^2 =e$ to get
$$
    aba = b
$$
Multiply on the right by $a$ and remember that $a^2 =e$ to get
$$
    ab = ba
$$

Comment: Did you mean to write that $x^2 = x,\; \forall x\in G;$ is a simplification of the property that every element in G is of order 1 or 2?  Wouldn't we rather have that $x^2 = e, \; \forall x \in G\;?

Comment: Take the abelian group the Klein-IV Group: $G = \{e, a, b, c\}.\;$ $e = e^2 = a^2 = b^2 = c^2$, but $a^2 \neq a, b^2 \neq b, c^2 \neq c...$.  We also know that $a\cdot b = c, a\cdot c = b, b \cdot c = a$.  So perhaps you can understand that I would question your second sentence in your answer.

Comment: Anyway, I corrected what I take to have been a typo...(My two comments above are addressing your claim that "every element is of order 1 or 2 can be simplified to $x^2 = x,$ for all $x\in G$.)

Comment: $a^2 = a \Longleftrightarrow a = e$!

Comment: @amWhy: Right you are.  Sorry for my typo. I was distracted by work and didn't keep track of my answer!

Comment: No problem...  It was clear to me, further on  in your proof that that's what you meant (I.e., originally just a typo; Believe me, I've had my share of typos!). I typically don't edit another's answer, but I also remember the times when I wish someone would have fixed one of my typos!  No worries;  your answer is fine!